# Merging two table into single table JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, append

I have two separate table, I want to merge into a single table using JQuery. But the out put I am seeing is not the correct one. Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Source Table

```
<html>
<table class="left-column">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Name
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Age
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
 </table>
 <table class="right-column">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Andy
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>30
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</html>
```

Target Table

```
<html>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="left-column">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Name
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Age
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
             </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table class="right-column">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Andy
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>30
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
             </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Jquery Code snippet

```
var leftTable=$('table.left-column').clone(); 
var rightTable=$('table.right-column').clone(); 
var newTable= $('div').append('<table><tr><td>')
    .append(leftTable).append('</td><td>')
    .append(rightTable).append('</td></tr></table>')
    .html(); 
return newTable;
```

Comment: please show what output you _are_ getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something [like this (jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/N4p3B/5/). This gives exactly the output you've requested in 3 short lines of code. (NOTE, this code actually MOVES the individual tables into the joined table instead of copying/cloning them.

```
$('div').html('<table border=1><tr><td id="cell1"></td><td id="cell2"></td></tr></table>');
$('#cell1').html($('.left-column').clone());
$('#cell2').html($('.right-column').clone());
```

Comment: This will not work for my scenario as it is modifying the parent HTML document, I need to show the merged table in the child window without modifying the parent window HTML.

Comment: Then just change it to this http://jsfiddle.net/N4p3B/5/. All you have to do is add `.clone()` to the last 2 lines. I've updated the code above in the main post.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, maybe something like this will work:

```
$('table.left-column').find('tr').each( function(i){
  $(this).append( $('table.right-column').find('tr').eq(i).find('td') ); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do this:

```
$('table').wrap('<td></td>')
          .parent().wrapAll('<table><tbody><tr></tr></tbody></table>');
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/6y4qt/

---

*If you have other tables on the page, then replace:*

```
$('table')
```

*with:*

```
$('.left-column,.right-column')
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
var leftTable = $(".left-column tbody").html();
var rightTable = $(".right-column tbody").html();

var newTable = "<table></table>";
return newtable.append(leftTable).append(rightTable);
```

Comment: This won't put the two tables side-by-side, will it?

Comment: it will append the trs of left column and right column to a single table

Answer (score 0):

You can't use "partial elements" like `'<table><tr><td>'`. Change the code to:

```
var leftTable  = $('table.left-column' ).clone();
var rightTable = $('table.right-column').clone();

var newTable   = $('div').append('<table><tr><td></td><td></td></tr></table>');
    newtable   = $('td:first', newtable).append(leftTable );
    newtable   = $('td:last' , newtable).append(rightTable);
```

Comment: The scenario I have is I have a parent window and I have to merge the two separate tables in the parent window to one table in the new child window. The above example modifies the parent window html.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a little more robust than you were looking for, but very reusable, here's a function that you can call and optionally pass a parent container to select tables within and the option to remove them from the page after processing them, but this will return to you all your tables in a combined structure like you specified.

```
function mergeTables(parent, remove){
    //if no parent is passed, default to body 
    if (!parent){
        parent = 'body';
    }

    //place to store the full HTML string of all the combined tables
    var table_html = '<table><tr>';
    //go through all tables
    $(parent).find('table').each(function(){
        //add their HTML to our big HTML string
        table_html += '<td><table>' + $(this).html() + '</table></td>';
        //remove that table from the page
        if (remove){
        $(this).remove();
    }
    });
    //close off and return the big HTML string
    return table_html + '</tr></table>';
}

//call example
$('#container').html( mergeTables('#container') );
```